# Steam Turbine - is it possible to run starting ejector and main ejector simultaneously for better efficiency?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, turbines, steam

In a steam turbine, is it possible to run the starting ejector of the surface condenser along with the main ejector?
Will it improve the efficiency of vacuum generation?

Comment: Hi @pat_nafs, it would be helpful if you would provide some pictures. Since I am not familiar with steam turbines and I need to rely on google results. As of now I would guess that the starting ejector only works at low massflows.